# Cudafy.Net System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022, cudafy.net

I downloaded cudafy here: https://github.com/lepoco/CUDAfy.NET/releases/tag/v.1.0.0.
I use VS 2022, .NET 4.8.
When executing this code, I get System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception.

```
            CudafyModes.Target = eGPUType.Cuda;
            CudafyModes.DeviceId = 0;
            CudafyTranslator.Language = CudafyModes.Target == eGPUType.OpenCL ? eLanguage.OpenCL : eLanguage.Cuda;

            if (CudafyHost.GetDeviceCount(CudafyModes.Target) == 0)
                throw new System.ArgumentException("No suitable devices found.", "original");

            GPGPU gpu = CudafyHost.GetDevice(CudafyModes.Target, CudafyModes.DeviceId);

            CudafyModule km = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy(); //THE EXCEPTION IS HERE
            gpu.LoadModule(km);
```

StackTrace:

```
   in System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   in Cudafy.NvccExe.getClExeDirectory()
   in Cudafy.CompilerHelper.Create(ePlatform platform, eArchitecture arch, eCudafyCompileMode mode, String workingDir, Boolean debugInfo)
   in Cudafy.Translator.CudafyTranslator.Cudafy()
   in Game.Position..ctor() in C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\simple\simple\Position.cs:line 464
   in Game.Position.StartPos() in C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\simple\simple\Position.cs:line 490
   in Game.Board..ctor() in C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\simple\simple\Board.cs:line 189
   in Game.FrmMain..ctor() in C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\simple\simple\FrmMain.cs:line 18
   in Game.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\simple\simple\Program.cs:line 19
```

Exception information:

```
        ErrorCode   -2147467259 int
        HResult -2147467259 int
        HelpLink    null    string
        InnerException  null
        NativeErrorCode 2   int
        Source  "System"    string
        TargetSite  {Boolean StartWithCreateProcess(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo)}   System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
```

The Path environment variable is declared:

```
Path C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\Hostx64\x64
```

Cuda Toolkit 11.6 has been downloaded.

What can I do about it?

Comment: That's not enough information to go on, try examining the properties on the exception: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.win32exception?view=net-6.0

Comment: I have added information about the exception.

Comment: OK, so you have a file not found exception: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-

Comment: the question is what file is it looking for?

Comment: This is perhaps an obvious question, but have you got the CUDA toolkit installed?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by connecting the source code. In particular, the program did not find the path to the utility vswhere.exe. Also the CUDA Toolkit required VS2010.